# Laravel 6 : A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I have migrate my website from Laravel 5.8 to Laravel 6, after a **composer update** i have this error on the website and also with just a command **php artisan** :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:242
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(48): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('check', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(376): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 242

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:242
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(48): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('check', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(376): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 242
```

I have taken a new laravel 6 file **config\app.php** and a new **.env**
But always this error...

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I know, the answer is a bit late :) But still I believe it could help someone else who will experience this issue.

The replacing all `str_slug()` methods by `Str::slug()` fixes the problem.
In my case, I found old helpers in the `config/cache.php` and `config/session.php` files.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i find a solution, i copy a laravel 6 config file : *config/session.php* and it's works.

Comment: In my case, I took also the `config/cache.php` file from the original repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting these errors - my own fault - I was moving my Laravel application files into a subdirectory, looks like `app.php` as well as a few other files were missing from my `/config/` directory:

```
cache.php
cors.php
filesystems.php
hashing.php
logging.php
mail.php
services.php
session.php
view.php
```

Should be:

```
app.php
auth.php
broadcasting.php
cache.php
cors.php
database.php
filesystems.php
hashing.php
logging.php
mail.php
queue.php
services.php
session.php
view.php
```