# Upgrade laravel 5.8 to 6: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade laravel 5.8 to 6.
I have also deleted the vendor Directory But still getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:258
```

````
#0 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(44): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('set', Array)
#1 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(376): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 258
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(44): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('set', Array)
#1 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(376): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp8.2.0\htdocs\web_kaalo - 5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 258```
````

Comment: did you read that question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084991/laravel-6-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084991/laravel-6-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 6 : A facade root has not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084991/laravel-6-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your composer.json file you should have this:

```
"laravel/framework": "^6.0",
"php": "^7.2",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
```

and then in console execute `composer update`, so if you are using the helpers String and Array
on this case you need install the package laravel/helpers with this command:

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

and after that change the helpers with calling to methods of classes
`Illuminate\Support\Str` and `Illuminate\Support\Arr`, if you have other issues please share here your composer.json for see more details.